# Writing a regular grammar for a regex of decimals

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

So I've got the regex `/[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?/` and I'm trying to write a **regular grammar** for it.

I started off like this:

```
S ∶≔ EAB
A ∶≔ DA | ε
B ∶≔ .AE | ε 
D ∶≔ 0 | 1 |  2 | 3 |  4 | 5 |  6 | 7 |  8 | 9
E ∶≔ 1 | 2 |  3 | 4 |  5 | 6 |  7 | 8 |  9
```

But I realised that this does not follow Chomsky's rules for regular grammars. So I was wondering how could I adapt this logic into proper notation.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** So below is the NDFA generated from the regex above:

[image]

Comment: Careful: not every (programmers') regexp defines a *regular* language.

Answer (score 1):

Regular grammars (of the right-regular variety) are essentially equivalent to NFAs, in the sense that they include roughly the same information. Once you convert your regular expression to an NFA, you can easily construct from it a right-regular grammar.

What doesn't seem possible is adapting your logic to construct a regular grammar. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to convert an arbitrary context-free grammar to a regular one; indeed, it is undecidable to determine whether a given context-free grammar corresponds to a regular language.

Comment: It can be fairly easy to define a regular grammar from the language generated by a regular expression. But in this case, I can't seem to figure out how I would write this expression in the grammar.

Comment: You would first convert the regular expression to an NFA, and then convert the NFA to a regular grammar. Both conversions have simple algorithms for accomplishing them.

Comment: I added the NDFA/NFA generated from the regex, how can i read it into the grammar

Comment: Take it as an exercise. The basic idea is to have each non-terminal correspond to a state, and each production rule correspond to a transition or to a final state. If you are using epsilon transitions, you need to eliminate them first.

Comment: Can a start symbol S ::= εD, D ::= 0|1|2|..|9 ?

Comment: The rule $S\to D$ isn't valid according to the definition. I suggest working on it for a few hours, the definition of regular grammars at your side.